# Primal-Dual basic (feasible) solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have been struggling with the following questions, especially the first two:

1. Is the solution $[y_1, y_2]^T = [2,1]$ of the dual a feasible solution?
2. Is the solution $[y_1, y_2]^T = [2,1]$ of the dual a basic solution?
3. Find the optimal solution $[y_1*, y_2*]^T$.

The following primal is given:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{min } & z = -4x_1 - 7x_2 + 5x_3 -14x_4\\
\text{s.t. } & 2x_1 -4x_2 + x_3  -8x_4  \leq 22 \\
& x_1 +  x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4  \leq 8 \\
& x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$$

If I am not mistaken, this should be equivalent to:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{min } & z = -4x_1 - 7x_2 + 5x_3 -14x_4\\
\text{s.t. } & -2x_1 +4x_2 - x_3  +8x_4  \geq -22 \\
& -x_1 -  x_2 - 3x_3 - x_4  \geq -8 \\
& x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Which should corresponds to the following dual:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{max } & w = -22y_1 -8y_2\\
\text{s.t. } & -2y_1 - y_2 \leq -4 \\
& 4y_1 -y_2 \leq -7\\
&-y_1 -3y_2 \leq 5\\
&8y_1 -y_2 \leq -14\\
& y_1, y_2 \geq 0 \\
\end{array}$$

My thoughts:

1. It is not a feasible solution, since for $y_1 = 2, y_2 = 1$ we have
   $$\begin{array}{cc}
   & -2y_1 - y_2 = -5 \neq -4 \\
   & 4y_1 -y_2 = 7 \neq -7\\
   &-y_1 -3y_2 = -5\neq 5\\
   &8y_1 -y_2 = 15\neq -14\\
   \end{array}$$
2. By that same argument, it is not a basic solution, since there is no basis $B$ of row vectors in $A^T$ such that $By_B = c$.
3. I assume this is simply done by the Dual simplex algorithm, starting with a basic solution. But it feel like I did something incorrect at (1) and (2) and I actually need to use $[2,1]$ for this.

I am familiar with complementary slackness, but I don't think this is useful here?

Comment: Note that you have inequalities in your dual problem. Thus only the second and the fourth constraint are not fullfilled. But this alone is sufficient that (2,1) is not a feasible solution.

Comment: So a basic solution, that is not necessarily feasible, has to satisfy all constraints of a LP? 

Does it also have to satisfy the non-negativity constraint? So if for example $[2,-1]^T$ satisfies the first four inequalities, then it's still not a basic solution because $y_2 < 0$?

Comment: A basic solution is a feasible solution. Because it is a feasibille solution it has to fullfill all constraints. $(2,-1)^T$ is not a basic (feasible) solution, because it does not fullfill the non-negativity condition.

Comment: If there is no typo number 2 can be answered immediately.

Comment: @callculus I searced "basic infeasible solution", and found "basic infeasible solution" on P.9 of this OR notes [$\unicode{x1F517}$](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~angelia/ge330fall09_stform4.pdf)

Comment: @user260710 How can $[2, -1]^T$ satisfy the equalities?  For example, in the fourth one, we have $$8y_1-y_2 = 8(2) - (-1) = 17 \color{red}{>} -14.$$

Comment: The term "basic solution" is often used to include basic solutions that are infeasible with respect to non-negativity constraints.  In that case you also consider a "basic feasible solution" which is basic and feasible.

Answer (score 1):

1. $[y_1, y_2]^T = [2,1]$ is *not* a feasible solution to the dual since it doesn't satisfy the first constraint  $4y_1 -y_2 = 7 > -7$.
2. $[y_1, y_2]^T = [2,1]$ is *not* a basic solution.  You may say "by the same *calculations*", but not "by the same *arguments*".
   \begin{align}
   4y_1 -y_2 = 7 > -7 &\implies [y_1, y_2]^T \text{ infeasible} \\
   4y_1 -y_2 = 7 \ne -7 &\implies [y_1, y_2]^T \text{ non-basic}
   \end{align}
   The second implication follows since we actually transform the LP into
   \begin{array}{lrr}
   \text{max} & w = -22y_1 -8y_2 &\\
   \text{s.t.} & -2y_1 - y_2 +s_1 =& -4 \\
   & 4y_1 -y_2 +s_2 =& -7\\
   &-y_1 -3y_2 +s_3 =& 5\\
   &8y_1 -y_2 +s_4 =& -14\\
   & y_1, y_2, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4 \geq 0
   \end{array}
   The calculations in the question body actually shows that $s_i$'s are nonzero, so the solution $[y_1,y_2]^T$ has *more than two* nonzero components, so it's *not* a basic solution.
3. You have the right choice of method.  To use the dual simplex method, we need a basic (*infeasible*) solution with the *optimality* satisfied.  Note that feasibility and optimality are two *independent* concepts.  It's easy to observe that in the simplex tableau, the $w$-row ($[22, 8, 0,\dots,0]$) is *nonnegative*, so the optimality condition is satisfied. As a result, the most obvious choice for a basic variable would be $[y_1,y_2]^T=[0,0]$.

Before continuing the dual simplex method, in response to OP's comment corcerning $[y_1,y_2]^T = [2, -1]$, we have $s_1 = -4 + 2(2) + (-1) = -1 \ne 0$, so $[y_1,y_2]^T = [2,-1]$ has more than two nonzero components, so it's nonbasic and infeasible.  We can't use this to solve the dual.

Current basis:  $s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4$

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
             &  y_1 & y_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 &     \\ \hline
         s_1 &   -2 &  -1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  -4 \\
         s_2 &    4 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  -7 \\
         s_3 &   -1 &  -3 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   5 \\
         s_4 &    8 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 & -14 \\ \hline
             &   22 &   8 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
\text{ratio} & 11/4 &  -8 &     &     &     &   0 & 
\end{array}

Leaving variable: $s_4$, entering variable: $y_2$

Current basis:  $s_1, s_2, s_3, y_2$

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr|r}
    & y_1 & y_2 & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 &      \\ \hline
s_1 & -10 &   0 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  -1 &   10 \\
s_2 &  -4 &   0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  -1 &    7 \\
s_3 & -25 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  -3 &   47 \\
y_2 &  -8 &   1 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  -1 &   14 \\ \hline
    & \color{blue}{86} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{\bbox[2px, border: solid 1px]{8}} & -112 \\
\end{array}

Hence the optimal solution is $[y_1,y_2]^T = [0,14]$ with $w = -112$.

By adding slack variabes $t_1,t_2$ to the primal

\begin{array}{rlr}
\min z =  & \color{red}{-4x_1 - 7x_2 + 5x_3 -14x_4} &\\
\text{s.t.} & 2x_1 -4x_2 + x_3  -8x_4 +\color{blue}{t_1} &= 22 \\
& x_1 +  x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4 +\color{blue}{t_2} &= 8 \\
& \color{red}{x_1, x_2, x_3, \bbox[2px, border: solid 1px]{x_4}}, \color{blue}{t_1,t_2} \geq 0,
\end{array}

we can read the solution of the primal from the simplex tableau for the dual:  the optimal solution for the primal is $[\color{red}{x_1, x_2, x_3, \bbox[2px, border: solid 1px]{x_4}}, \color{blue}{t_1,t_2}]^T = [\color{red}{0,0,0, \bbox[2px, border: solid 1px]{8}}, \color{blue}{86,0}]$.